# Equivalent definition of independence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, independence

Fix a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \Bbb P),$ and random variables $X, Y: \Omega \rightarrow \Bbb R.$ Consider now the following two statements:

1. $X$ and $Y$ are independent,
2. There is no measurable $f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ such that $Y = f \circ X.$

Statement 2 would coincide with my intuition of when 2 functions are independent in general. Thus, I am interested in the relationships between the two statements. Are those equivalent under perhaps slightly stronger assumptions/modifications?

Comment: Independence of $X$ and $Y$ in the traditional sense of Statement 1 strongly involves how the probability measure $\mathbb P$ behaves on intersections of sets from the $\sigma$-algebras generated by $X$ resp. by $Y$. Statement 2 has no knowledge about a probability measure whatsoever. In particular : the statements are clearly not equivalent. I also do not believe that one can make slight modifications to achieve this.

Comment: It seems that this is another manifestation of the [confusion](https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/correlation-vs-causation) between probabilistic dependence (correlation) and *causal* dependence.

Answer (score 2):

1 implies 2. but 2 doesn't imply 1. For example, take $X$ uniform in $\{0,1,2\}$ and $Y$ such that $Y$ is randomly and uniformly chosen to be one of the two values $X$ doesn't take. So $Y$ is not a function of $X$. But $Y$ and $X$ aren't independent.